# Resolving highest product in an array swift

Tags: swift

I have an work to get highest product I could get in an array of Ints.

> Given an array of integers, find the highest product you can get from
>   three of the integers. If array size is less than 3, please printout
>   -1

here is what I tried which returned `20`

```
func adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: [Int]) -> Int {
    let sorted = inputArray.sorted()
    let count = sorted.count
    if count > 1 {
        return max(sorted[0] * sorted[1] * sorted[2], sorted[count - 1] * sorted[count - 2] * sorted[count - 3])
    } else {
        return sorted.first ?? 0
    }
}

adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: [3, 1, 2, 5, 4])
```

it how ever fails for this test case

```
adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: [1, 10, -5, 1, -100])
```

it returns 500 and 5000 is expected

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202754/discussion-on-question-by-king-resolving-highest-product-in-an-array-swift).

Comment: repost of identical question deleted seconds before posting this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954867/getting-highest-product-of-an-array-swift

Answer (score 0):

```
func adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: [Int]) -> Int {
    let sorted = inputArray.sorted()

    let count = sorted.count

    guard count >= 3 else {
        return -1
    }

    return max(
       sorted[count - 1] * sorted[count - 2] * sorted[count - 3],
       sorted[count - 1] * sorted[0] * sorted[1]
    )
}
```

How does it work?

There are three cases to consider. The highest product is either

1. The product of the 3 highest positive numbers
2. The product of the highest positive number multiplicated by the the product of the two lowest negative numbers (the negatives cancel out)
3. The product of the 3 lowest negative numbers if there are only negative numbers.

Cases 1 and 3 are covered by `sorted[count - 1] * sorted[count - 2] * sorted[count - 3]`. Case 2 is covered by `sorted[count - 1] * sorted[0] * sorted[1]`.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, that is  (now) what @King had posted.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, since I was writing without testing, I got confused with the direction of sorting.

Answer (score -2):

```
func adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: [Int]) -> Int {
    let sorted = inputArray.sorted()
    let count = sorted.count
    if count < 3 {
        return -1
    } else {
        return max(sorted[0] * sorted[1] * sorted[count - 1],
        sorted[count - 1] * sorted[count - 2] * sorted[count - 3])
    }
}
```

Comment: @MartinR of course, sorting in reverse :) I am blind

Comment: According to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-maximum-product-of-a-triplet-in-array (Approach 3) the above code *is* the correct solution to this problem.